# Use a different array every time you call a function JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So I have a bunch of arrays that look like,

```
var arr = [characterA, characterB, characterC];
var arr2 = [characterC, characterA, characterB];
var arr3 = [characterB, characterC, characterA];
```

and I'm doing something with these (what isn't important) but it looks like,

```
    arr[0].alignTo(columnLeft, Phaser.LEFT_CENTER);
    arr[1].alignIn(columnLeft, Phaser.CENTER);
    arr[2].alignTo(columnLeft, Phaser.RIGHT_CENTER);
```

It's within a function called `toggle()` like so,

```
  toggle:function() {
    var arr = [characterA, characterB, characterC];
    var arr2 = [characterC, characterA, characterB];
    var arr3 = [characterB, characterC, characterA];

    arr[0].alignTo(columnLeft, Phaser.LEFT_CENTER);
    arr[1].alignIn(columnLeft, Phaser.CENTER);
    arr[2].alignTo(columnLeft, Phaser.RIGHT_CENTER);

    timer.add(1000, this.toggle, this);
  },
```

So what I'm trying to do, is basically, everytime I call this function. I use a different set of `arrays` so at the moment where I'm doing `arr[0]` how would I write that so that each time the function is called it uses `arr2` and then after that `arr3` then after that back to `arr` and so forth.

I've been fighting with this for a day or so.

Comment: You mean, each call to `toggle` would us *one* of them (`arr`), and the next call would use the next (`arr2`), and the next call would use the next (`arr3`)?

Comment: Sorry may of explained it wrong. Yes exactly as you said it @T.J.Crowder

Comment: The three calls, as in `alignTo` etc should use the same array just different indexes. So like `alignTo` users the first item in the array, the second uses the second item in the array and so fourth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean each call to `toggle` would us *one* of them (`arr`), and the next call would use the next (`arr2`), and the next call would use the next (`arr3`), you can put them in an array and remember the index of the next array to use:

```
// Outside the function
var arr = [characterA, characterB, characterC];
var arr2 = [characterC, characterA, characterB];
var arr3 = [characterB, characterC, characterA];
var arrays = [arr, arr2, arr3];
var index = 0;

// In the function:
toggle:function() {
    var thisArray = arrays[index];
    index = ++index % arrays.length; // Wraps around if necessary
    thisArray[0].alignTo(columnLeft, Phaser.LEFT_CENTER);
    thisArray[1].alignIn(columnLeft, Phaser.CENTER);
    thisArray[2].alignTo(columnLeft, Phaser.RIGHT_CENTER);

    timer.add(1000, this.toggle, this);
},
```

If the arrays **have** to be built within `toggle` itself, we just keep `index` outside and build only the array we need:

```
// Outside the function
var index = 0;

// In the function:
toggle:function() {
    var arr;
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            arr = [characterA, characterB, characterC];
            break;
        case 1:
            arr = [characterC, characterA, characterB];
            break;
        case 2:
            arr = [characterB, characterC, characterA];
            break;
    }
    index = ++index % 3; // Wraps around if necessary
    arr[0].alignTo(columnLeft, Phaser.LEFT_CENTER);
    arr[1].alignIn(columnLeft, Phaser.CENTER);
    arr[2].alignTo(columnLeft, Phaser.RIGHT_CENTER);

    timer.add(1000, this.toggle, this);
},
```

Comment: I did need to build the array within the toggle method and this worked thanks dude! `index = ++index % arrays.length;` should be `index = ++index % arr.length;`

Comment: @PourMeSomeCode: No, it shouldn't. :-) It should be `3`, I just forgot to change it for the second code sample (fixed now). It's related to the number of cases we have, not the number of items inside `arr` (even though, coincidentally, both of those values are 3).